# Observable property allowing to add observers at runtime

Tags: properties, kotlin, observable

Via `Delegates.observable`, Kotlin permits observable properties. I need, however, the ability of adding observers at runtime, as Java's `Observable` class does.

What I have now, is the following:

```
import java.util.*
import kotlin.reflect.KProperty
import kotlin.reflect.KProperty0
import kotlin.reflect.jvm.isAccessible


class MyObservable<T> (var v: T): java.util.Observable() {

    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any, prop: KProperty<*>) = v
    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any, prop: KProperty<*>, newValue: T) {
        v = newValue
        setChanged()
        notifyObservers()
    }
}

fun <T> addObserver(prop: KProperty0<T>, observerFn: (T) -> Unit) =
        (prop.apply{ isAccessible = true }.getDelegate() as MyObservable<T>)
                .addObserver(Observer({ o, _ -> observerFn((o as MyObservable<T>).v) }))


class ObservableExample {
    var i: Int by MyObservable(3)
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val ex: ObservableExample = ObservableExample();

    addObserver(ex::i, { println(it) })

    ex.i = 7
    ex.i = 9

    // prints:
    // 7
    // 9
}
```

It works, but it feels like reinventing the wheel.

Isn't there a standard solution for this?

If not, is what I've done correct?

Answer (score 2):

A slightly shorter variant of the same idea:

```
import kotlin.properties.Delegates

typealias IntObserver = (Int) -> Unit

class ObservableExample {
    val prop1Observers = mutableListOf<IntObserver>()

    var prop1: Int by Delegates.observable(0) { prop, old, new ->
        prop1Observers.forEach { it(new) }
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val example = ObservableExample()
    example.prop1Observers.add({ println(it) })
    example.prop1 = 1
    example.prop1 = 2
}
```

The output is as expected. Probably, it is better to make `observers` property private and add a method to add subscribers but I omitted it for the simplicity.

Comment: arent we in risk of Concurrent modification?

Comment: Depends on the use case. But in general, yes - we are. Can be solved with locks or `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you starts with a simple example, and can't find the benefits of Kotlin [delegated properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html).

Kotlin doesn't forcing you to implements any interface to supports [delegated properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html), yon can using [delegated properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html) in Kotlin just provide [getValue & setValue(?)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#property-delegate-requirements) operators. and their visibility even can be **private**.

Kotlin provided a [provideDelegate](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#providing-a-delegate-since-11) operator function since 1.1, that let you manage/control **how** to create a delegate.

The delegate in Kotlin is working in the **background**, which means it is **invisible** from the source code point of view, and let the code source treat a [delegated properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html) as a regular properties.

Kotlin [delegated properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html) can easily let you manage java beans without using [PropertyEditorSupport](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyEditorSupport.html) in Java, and you don't need to manage the delegate at all in Kotlin, just to notify the changed property only. for example:

```
val history = mutableMapOf<String, MutableList<Pair<Any?, Any?>>>()
val subject = Subject()

subject.subscribe { event ->
    val each = history.getOrPut(event.propertyName) { mutableListOf() }
    each.add(event.oldValue to event.newValue)
}

//      v--- treat a delegated property as regular property
subject.number = 1
subject.string = "bar"
subject.number = 2

println(history);
//      ^--- {"number":[<null,1>,<1,2>], "string": [<null,"bar">]}
```

---

Note: the [getValue & setValue](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#property-delegate-requirements) operator functions **private** below.

```
class Subject {
    //                     v--- manage the delegated property internally
    var string: String? by this
    var number: Int? by this

    private val properties by lazy {
        mutableMapOf<Any?, Any?>()
    }
    private val listeners by lazy {
        mutableListOf<PropertyChangeListener>()
    }

    private operator @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    fun <T : Any?> getValue(self: Any, prop: KProperty<*>): T {
        return properties[prop.name] as T
    }

    private operator 
    fun <T : Any?> setValue(self: Any,prop: KProperty<*>, newValue: T) {
        val event = PropertyChangeEvent(
                self,
                prop.name,
                properties[prop.name],
                newValue
        )
        properties[prop.name] = newValue
        listeners.forEach { it.propertyChange(event) }
    }

    fun subscribe(listener: (event: PropertyChangeEvent) -> Unit) {
        subscribe(PropertyChangeListener { listener(it) })
    }

    fun subscribe(subscriber: PropertyChangeListener) {
        listeners.add(subscriber)
    }
}
```